# How to build LLVM-<current-version>.dll with Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, build, llvm

Following the instructions [here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html), 
I've installed prerequisites, downloaded the source for version 3.9 and had CMake generate `LLVM.sln`. Building the full solution takes some times, but seems to do what it's supposed to do.

When looking at `get_library` in `bindings/python/llvm/common.py`, the Python binding makes use of a file named "`LLVM-`*<current version>*`.dll`" but I can't find any "`LLVM-3.9.dll`" in the generated files.

How do I build `LLVM-3.9.dll` from source with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [my repository](https://github.com/anhoavu/LibLLVM) which is based on [CRoger instructions](https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries) and simply build the project `LLVM.vcxproj` in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried to build 'Release' and got a huge list of warnings, that I didn't get with 'Debug'.

Comment: Hey, where's LibLLVM gone?

Comment: @StijnSanders The C API doesn't work in my case since I need full compiler so I deleted the effort.

Comment: What is the part for a full compiler you can't do with the C API?

Comment: @StijnSanders The `CompilerInstance` stuffs that does source -> object files.

Comment: Is that what's [LLVMCreateObjectFile](https://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/group__LLVMCObject.html#ga0fd9f7bc65117c049c14c047fb7907dc) is for?

Comment: @StijnSanders Nope. You need the full C++ API to compile a *.c or *.cpp to object.